# How to render only an embedded table after removing a row - search expression problem

Tags: jsf, el, jsf-2.3

I've one table embedded into another table. My problem: How to render only the inner table when a row was removed?

Bean:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5633666299306108430L;
    private List<String> strLst1;
    private List<String> strLst2;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        strLst1 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        strLst2 = Arrays.asList("d", "e", "f");
    }

    public List<String> getStrLst1() {
        return strLst1;
    }

    public List<String> getStrLst2() {
        return strLst2;
    }

    public void removeFromStrLst2(String val) {
        strLst2.remove(val);
    }
}
```

Facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <h:form id="form">
    <h:dataTable
      id="outerTable"
      var="str1"
      value="#{testBean.strLst1}"
      border="1">
      <h:column>
        <h:panelGroup id="innerTableContainer">
          <h:dataTable
            id="innerTable"
            var="str2"
            value="#{testBean.strLst2}"
            border="1">
            <h:column>
              <h:outputText value="#{str1}: #{str2}" />
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
              <h:commandButton
                id="removeButton"
                action="#{testBean.removeFromStrLst2(str2)}"
                value="RemoveFromStrLst2">
                <f:ajax render="innerTableContainer" /> <!-- Problem location -->
              </h:commandButton>
            </h:column>
          </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
  </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

My problem is the Ajax-render attribute which doesn't get the correct id (examples for the first row):

`innerTableContainer` leads to `mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'innerTableContainer')` It doesn't work!

`innerTable` leads to `mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form:outerTable:0:innerTable:0')` It doesn't work!

`@parent` leads to `mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form:outerTable:0:innerTable:0:j_idt14')` It doesn't work!

`@namingcontainer` leads to `mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form:outerTable:0:innerTable:0')` It doesn't work!

`@form` works but this isn't I was looking for.

The correct and working id would be `form:outerTable:0:innerTableContainer` but how to get it?

Mojarra 2.3.9.SP01

Comment: Try `@namingcontainer:@namingcontainer` or similar, it will work too, you can 'chain' them

Comment: And effectively your title is too specific. It is not (data)table and row related...

Comment: @Kukeltje: No, leads to `mojarra.ab(this,event,'action',0,'form:outerTable:0')` and so, doesn't work. The correct id has to be `form:outerTable:0:innerTableContainer` as I've written above.

Comment: 'Or similar' I said... .... so add `:innerTableContainer` to it...

Comment: @Kukeltje: Okay, thx, `@namingcontainer:@namingcontainer:innerTableContainer` works, but it's not clear to me why `@namingcontainer` doesn't work.

Comment: Because it take the first namingcontainer up the tree. Maybe `:@namingcontainer:@parent` works too